# phantomjs: how to generate a perfect html screenshot?

Tags: phantomjs

When I use control + s to save a page completely in my browser, and I open it, it more or less resembles the original website.

however, when I render a site on phantomjs and look at the generated html, it looks very different from the screenshot it produces.

how does phantomjs produce a good accurate image screenshot but not a good html screenshot? for example, when I take a screenshot of futureshop.ca and look at the html generated by phantomjs it looks  like a completely different website. how do we resolve this?

for example take this cgi proxy:

https://ultraproxy.us/perl/nph-proxy.cgi/en/00/http/www.bestbuy.ca/ (uses perl cgi)

vs.

http://prerender.herokuapp.com/http://www.bestbuy.ca (using phantomjs)

how does a perl cgi script produce a more accurate looking page? is there a way to get phantomjs to do the same? phantomjs has the advantage of handling ajax loaded content while the perl cgi wouldn't.